# How to call methods in the custom view in iOS module, from titanium project?

Tags: ios, module, titanium

I need to call methods in the custom view in iOS module from titanium project. I have followed the tutorials in Appcelarator documentation  about creating iOS module. I could create the custom view in Titanium using below code.

```
var manage = require('com.test');
var manageView = manage.createView({
left:40,
right:40,
top:40,
height: 250,
backgroundColor:'blue' });  manageView.customMethodInView();
```

But i got error like "customMethodInView is not a function"  when i run the app.

```
#import "TiViewProxy.h"
#import "CustomView.h"

@interface ComTestViewProxy : TiViewProxy {
    CustomView *customView;
}
- (void) customMethodInView;
@end
```

This is the code in viewProxy class in iOS Module project.
Please help.

Comment: did you enter the bridging header as TiViewProxy is in obj-c and you are using swift

Answer (score 0):

I know this is late, but for any wondering soul out there, it is my understanding that even if you don't intend to pass an argument for your method, the signature of the method in the native module should always take one:

your method

```
- (void) customMethodInView;
```

should look like this :

```
- (void)customMethodInView:(id)unused;
```